# not able to see video file content in disc

Tags: video, vlc

I am user of kubuntu 14.04 lts. Whenever I insert any video disc, in notification bar it shows you have 4 action for this device and if I choose vlc it start playing video, but when I open file manager it doest show any video file in it.
It shows only .dat .rtf .app .vcd file but how to see and open video file. I want to copy video file from my disc to laptop. I am using dragon player and vlc player. Please help me thank you